# AngularJS : $state.transitionTo('myState') keeps reloading angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am currently implementing a simple user authentication and I want the user to only be able to view some states if the user is loggedin and the token is not null. This is because on my ionic app, when i refresh a state, it immediately goes to my default page even though the user has been logged in and the user has a token.

So in my app.js, i did the following to check if the user can go to the state,

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

$ionicLoading.show({
  template: 'Loading...'
});

if (window.sessionStorage.token) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = window.sessionStorage.token;  
  $rootScope.localTokenKey = window.sessionStorage.token;
  $rootScope.isLoggedin = true;
}
else {
  $rootScope.isLoggedin = false;
}

if(toState.data) {
  if(!$rootScope.isLoggedin){
    $state.transitionTo('login', {}, { reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true})
  }
} else {
  console.log("FAILED")
}
```

})

$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    $ionicLoading.hide(); 
  });

state provider config
This is the list of the states.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {


      $stateProvider
      //$controllerProvider.allowGlobals();

      .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
      })

      .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })

      .state('app.dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/dashboard.html",
          }
        },
        authenticate : true
      })

      .state('app.case_status', {
        url: "/case_status",
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/case_listing.html",
            controller: 'ReferralCtrl'
          }
        },
        authenticate : true
      })
      .state('app.case_status_single', {
        url: "/case_details",
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/case_details.html",
            controller: 'ReferralCtrl'
          }
        },
        authenticate : true

      })

      .state('app.feedback', {
        url: "/feedback",
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/feedback.html"
          }
        },
        authenticate : true

      })

      .state('app.new', {
        url: "/new_referral",
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/new_referral.html",
            controller: 'NewCaseCtrl'
          }
        },
        authenticate : true
      })

      .state('app.settings', {
        url: "/settings",
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/settings.html"
          }
        },
        authenticate : true
      })

      .state('logout', {
          url: "/logout",
          views: {
            'menuContent' : {
            }
          } 
      });

      // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
     //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    })
```

When i run my code, the console.log("login page") is executed more than 1000times before it hits an unidentified error then the login page is shown.

What am i doing wrong and how can i solve this issue. I am using AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother intercepting and preventing the state change if you don't need to do anything (ie, user is logged in).

Also, I'd change the logic to look for a `public` flag instead of your `authenticate` flag and assume all states require authentication. In fact, I'd say the fact that your *"login"* state evaluates `toState.authenticate` to `false` is the root of your problem.

Finally, extra state data should go in the `data` property.

To summarise

1. Use a `public` flag on any state that is publicly available

   ```
   .state('login', {
       url: "/login",
       templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
       controller: 'AppCtrl',
       data: {
           public: true
       }
   })
   ```

   and remove the `authenticate` properties from the other states.
2. Check for the `public` flag **or** `$rootScope.isLoggedIn` and go to your `login` state if both are false

   ```
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
       $ionicLoading.show({
         template: 'Loading...'
       });

       if (!((toState.data && toState.data.public) || $rootScope.isLoggedIn)) {
           console.log("login page")
           event.preventDefault(); 
           $state.transitionTo('login', {}, { reload: true, inherit: true, notify: true});
       }
   })
   ```

Comment: thanks your solution works as now it doesnt refresh a million times but now after logging in, when i refresh a particular page, it still sends me back to the login page. is there anyway of catching that. i read a few places tht it is not good to use cookies but do i hv to end up using tht so tht once it is logged in if i refresh the page, it has a record tht it is logged in nd doesnt set all d values back to false

Comment: @KingsleySimon You'll need to store the *authentication* state somewhere ([`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) would be my pick), read from that during your app's startup and assign `$rootScope.isLoggedIn` appropriately

Comment: i set the stored the token using sessionStorage but for example upon login, it goes to the dashboard page. if i refresh the dashboard page, it still returns to d login page.  i made some edits to my initial code to explain better.